# Implementation of having [0,2] rows, but not more, with similar data

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am implementing an access database, using MS Access 2016. I am trying to create a table that has some columns, where 2 of them are a combined foreign key.

Now, I want each value of the foreign key to be usable a maximum of **2 times**, in the new table. If a user tries to use the same value, a third time, then the program should give an error.

I haven't been able to find an answer to this question anywhere else.

```
Original table: Field1  Field2
                  1        2
                  2        2
New table: Field1(FK) Field2(FK)PK Field3 PK
              1         2            3
              1         2            4
              1         2            5      <---- Generate error
```

FK - Foreign Key

PK - Primary Key

**EDIT1:** I want to clarify that I want **Field1** and **Field2** in **New Table** to have the required functionality.

**EDIT2:** To give an example of my problem, I have a basketball game (Field1: StartingTime Field2: Stadium). For this game, I need 2 teams. Therefore I have a table GameTeams. But there cannot be more than 2 teams, thus I need this limitation of 2. In other words, each Game has 2 Gameteams. Hopefully this gives a better understanding.

Comment: Hmm, this sounds like questionable table design, or at least like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/305412). Can you explain why you need this?

Comment: And your use of `PK` is confusing - the first two rows already violate it.

Comment: oh, I'm sorry about that. The 3 should obviously be different

Comment: The thing is, this table represents something that means, for each row in Original Table, there are [0,2] rows in the New Table that has a row in Original Table as foreign key. I just want to restrict this to 2

Comment: your theory still doesn't work when user enters field1 = 1, field2 =1. Same team cannot compete itself? but valid entry in your case :) ;)

Comment: Field 3 is the team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Access 2010 and later you can accomplish your goal by using a saved query that counts the rows associated with each (Field1,Field2) pair ...

[image: QueryDesign.png]

... along with a Before Change [data macro](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200) on your table to check for existing related rows:

[image: BeforeChange.png]

Comment: Thank you for this reply. I had not been thinking about using Macros at all. It works perfectly fine with the same syntax, even on Access 2016.